# Javascript, variable is not getting assigned... why?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Here is my most simple code:

```
var this_version =null;

this.timervar = setTimeout(function () {
    try {
        // Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
        Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
        AddonManager.getAddonByID("parasites@maafire.com", function(addon) {
            this_version = addon.version;
            alert("r "+this_version);
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
        var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
        var addon = em.getItemForID("parasites@maafire.com");
        this_version = addon.version;
        alert("rr " + this_version);
    }
    alert("rrr " + this_version);
}, 2000);
```

and its so damn strange because this fires twice `alert("r "+this_version);` but this `alert("rrr "+this_version);` always gives me null ;(

Still learning JS , so this is pretty puzzling... please help!

Thanks!

Comment: No one is going to bother looking at your code when it's formatted like that

Comment: So what got alerted with the single r?  And did the alert with the triple r happen before the alert with the single r?

Comment: first i get `r 0.5` then `rrr null` then `r 0.5` then `rrr null`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, solved it by just moving all the stuff except for the alert out of the timer:

```
var this_version =null;
try {
    // Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
    AddonManager.getAddonByID("parasites@maafire.com", function(addon) {
        this_version = addon.version;
        alert("r "+this_version);
    });
} catch (ex) {
    // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
    var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
    var addon = em.getItemForID("parasites@maafire.com");
    this_version = addon.version;
    alert("rr " + this_version);
}

this.timervar = setTimeout(function ()
                            { 



                                    alert("rrr "+this_version);


                            }, 2000);
```

Comment: This is not a reliable solution. Waiting for 2 seconds doesn't guarantee that `this_version` is already set.

Answer (score 0):

Your code which sets the `this_version` variable is inside a callback, so changes to the variable won't be reflected in the scope in which your third `alert` executes.

Comment: So, how do I get that value into my variable so that I can use it in other places?

Comment: It's not a scope issue but a timing issue. Given that the code is running in a global context, all the functions are accessing the same *this_version* variable. Even if the outer context is function code, they will have a closure to the same instance since there is no other *this_version* on their scope chains. The problem is that the function given to *setTimeout* runs before the other functions have set the value, so at the time that it runs, the functions setting the value haven't been called yet.

Comment: @Ryan - presumably *Components* is making asynchronous AJAX requests (hence the timing issue). You might be able to fix that by making the calls synchronous, but it may not be what you want.

Comment: Since this runs async I figured it was a timing issue thats why I put it in a settimeout...hopeing that those 2 seconds would be enough for it to get what it needs and update the main variable that I can use elsewhere... but that did not work, how do you suggest I do this then?

Comment: Using setTimeout to call *Components* will just delay everything. You can try polling using *setInterval* (ugly as the XHR may never complete successfully and hence not set the variable). You may need a controller function that is told when the XHR calls are made so the controller sets a flag (object property, whatever). Have the callbacks tell it when they are done so it clears the flag. As each returns, the controller checks if any are left to clear. If they're all done, it continues processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to do it in the JavaScript world:

```
function done() {
    alert("rrr "+this_version);
}

var this_version =null;
try {
    // Firefox 4 and later; Mozilla 2 and later
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
    AddonManager.getAddonByID("parasites@maafire.com", function(addon) {
        this_version = addon.version;
        alert("r "+this_version);
        done();
    });
} catch (ex) {
    // Firefox 3.6 and before; Mozilla 1.9.2 and before
    var em = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager);
    var addon = em.getItemForID("parasites@maafire.com");
    this_version = addon.version;
    alert("rr " + this_version);
    done();
}
```

or even better:

```
function done(version) {
    alert("rrr "+version);
}
```

then call it like this:

```
done(this_version);
```